# Nokia Qt Installation

Tags: qt, nokia

Recently I installed Nokia Qt SDK in my Windows machine but as I do with other installations, installed the SDK in different directory from the default one it suggested i.e C:\NokiaQtSDK.
Alas I had to contend with lot of configuration issues because of this custom location.

Has anybody faced any such kind problem? Just want to know whether installing in custom location will hamper the development?

Comment: did you use a path with spaces? That's generally a problem with qmake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Qt SDK installed in a custom location, but I never had any issues. I also didn't have any configuration issues, it just works out of the box. 
I'm using it on different machines and different windows flavors (Windows 7, 32bit and 64bit version).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a lot of issues when project was not on the same drive as SDK. All problems were gone when both projects and SDK were installed to C:.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install QT in any directory you choose without much trouble. Just make sure you set your environment variable(s) to the right file path.

Here's how to do it in XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519